# Receiving unpredictable parameters in Struts2 interceptor

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, parameters, struts2, cache-control

I am aiming to write an interceptor that add some headers in response. I currently have the following interceptor

```
public class CachingInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor{

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) getActionContext(ai).get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);
        if(null != response) {
            response.setHeader("Cache-control","no-store,no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Expires","-1");
        }
        return ai.invoke();
    }
}
```

I need to enhance it in such a way that headers can be defined in configuration file (`struts.xml`)

```
....
<!-- Define and add following interceptor in default interceptor stack -->
<interceptor name="CachingInterceptor" class="demo.CachingInterceptor">
....

<action name="myAction" class="demo.myAction">
    ....
<param name="Cache-control">no-store,no-cache</param>
<param name="Pragma">no-cache</param>
<param name="Expires">-1</param>
    ....
</action>
```

Now I have to define properties in my interceptor class to get values for headers

```
private String pragma;     //with getter, setter
private String expires;    //with getter, setter
```

Here I have two problems.

1• I cannot define property "Cache-control" in java.

2• Header names are unpredictable, i.e. Any header can be defined in configuration as

```
    <param name="other-header">some-value</param>
```

I have two questions:

- How can I receive any header in interceptor defined in Struts2 configuration.
- Is there any better way to do this thing?

Comment: WTQ? You receive header in the static parameters that interceptor put. What is the better serves your requirement.

Comment: as described, i want to define http headers while mapping action in configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the action configuration you have defined several static parameters that are processed via the `staticParams` interceptor. This interceptor should proceed first in the stack. Then you have simply retrieve them from the action context.

```
Map<String, Object> params = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
response.setHeader("Cache-control", ((String[])params.get("Cache-control"))[0]);
response.setHeader("Pragma", ((String[])params.get("Pragma"))[0]);
response.setHeader("Expires", ((String[])params.get("Expires"))[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks `Roman C`, This answer provides the key to solution. I will update the answer after a little modification when I find some time to work on it.