# Passing a key value in query string from one page to another in a project using Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, query-string, url-parameters

I am trying to pass a key value in query string from one page to another in a project using the Struts 2 framework.

**URL Mapping:**

```xml
<struts>        
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <!-- Line -->
        <action name="line" class="com.example.a.b.action.LineAction">
            <result name="success">/line.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

**URL For HTML Anchor Link:**

```
http://localhost/line?key=value
```

When it goes to `LineAction` I want to get the query string key value part but could find anything online for it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly. In your action class create `Getters` and `Setters` for `key`. You will get a value in your action class.

May be You try this way..

```
     try{
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com?gender=male&name=jagga");
        System.out.println(url.getQuery());

     }catch(MalformedURLException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

You build your URL of that Action

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get parameters from the action context like

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
```

But a better way is to implement `ParameterAware`

```
private Map<String, String[]> parameters;

public void setParameters(Map<String, String[]> parameters){
  this.parameters = parameters;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working, I tried to get the key and value, all I got is [Ljava.lang.String;@2edf7aa6

Comment: What did you try? The code works fine. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15836720/573032) for example.